# How to design code to delete irrelevant value to maintain primary key for table

Tags: sql

I have a table where primary key is set of fields.
 name plus age is primary key
But there is a another field named membership which must say yes or no but in some case for this combination it has yes and no both values which is incorrect so I need to design query in such way that it should delete one which has yes when no already exist for primary key field

Table

```
Name -Xyz   age  20 membership yes 
Name Jkl    age  30 membership no
Name ABC    age  21 membership yes
Name ABC    age  21 membership no
```

In this case 'ABC' value with yes should be deleted because 'ABC' value with no should be considered

Comment: What is the logic of which ones should be deleted?

Comment: And please tag your question with the dbms you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by `membership` and keep the first row you find, effectively discarding a `yes` if a `no` exists.

For example:

```
select
  name, age, membership
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by name, age order by membership) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
name  age  membership
----  ---  ----------
-xyz   20  yes       
ABC    21  no        
jkl    30  no
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTzjGkhKn5QyfQzJYuxcqr/0).